# Image transparecy with another one backwards c#

Tags: c#, image, forms, background, transparent

I currently have some images (4) in front of a image background, the problem is, the image shape, collides with the other ones and the transparency it's not working well between them.

Ok, i have set the backcolor for those 4 images to Transparent, and then, set the parent for each one the back image, but this is what I see:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2EPs.png)

It seems that only refresh their parent (Background) some help?

Comment: What does the raw image look like?

Comment: The final result should looks like this: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/B7s402L) and the images in the form are put like this: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/qZ53qA1)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're adding pictureboxes or something similar , but this will make it very inefficient to work with.

You might want to consider creating an object which will take care of the image draw and add it to you base control which has you background image, something like this:

```
public class YellowGuy
{
   public Point Position {get; set;}
   public Size Size {get; set;}
   public Bitmap YellowGuyImage {get; set;}   

   public YellowGuy(Bitmap img, Point startPos, Size desiredSize)
   {
      YellowGuyImage = img;
      Size = desiredSize;
      Position = startPos;
   }

   public void Draw(Graphics g)
   {
      g.DrawImage(YellowGuyImage, new rectangle(Position, Size));
   }
}
```

In you main form (maybe, I don't know your code):

```
picturebox.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.picturebox_Paint);
List<YellowGuy> yellowGuys;
yellowGuys = new List<YellowGuy>();
yellowGuys.Add(new YellowGuy([some image],[some position],[some size])); //Do on a for, or how you wish, to add more guys.

//Control which draw images, here I used PictureBox to show you
private void picturebox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   foreach(var guy in yellowGuys)
   {
      guy.Draw(e.Graphics);
   }
}
```

You can just re-position a yellow guy accessing list and changing position and on the next refresh it will be drawn in the new position.
You might want to add an ID or Name to YellowGuy object so you can distinguish them.

BTW... I wrote the code here without testing, but I think important parts are all here.

Comment: Sorry but how can I call the picturebox_Paint event? Thanks :D

Comment: @Edgar_94_, I'm going to edit the post and add the event hooking. If you have a class which is inheriting from a picturebox, you can just override OnPaint.

Comment: It worked, thanks! but I want that the yellow guys moves on the background image and animate in that movement, i had a class that did that with the picturebox, but I don't know how to do that with g.DrawImage, thanks a lot :D